# Did I prove correctly this proposition which is in divisibility in unique factorization domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

The question is:

Let $\mathit D$ be a unique factorization domain and let $\mathit a, b, c \in D$. Suppose that $1_{D}$ is a gcd of $\mathit a$ and $\mathit b$. Prove that if $\mathit a\ |\ c$ and $\mathit b\ |\ c$ then $\mathit ab\ |\ c$.

Here is my proof:

Assume that $$\mathit a \sim p^{m_1}_{1}...p^{m_r}_{r}$$ and $$\mathit b \sim q^{n_1}_{1}...q^{n_s}_{s}$$ For $p_{1},...p_{r}, q_{1},...,q_{s}$, all of them are irreducible in $\mathit D$, each different two numbers are not associated and gcd of each different two numbers is $1_{D}$. $m_{1},...,m_{r},n_{1},...n_{s} \in \mathbb N$. Since $\mathit a\ |\ c$, we can write as $$\mathit c = p^{m_1}_{1}...p^{m_r}_{r}t$$ for some $\mathit t \in D$. And since gcd($\mathit p_{i}, q_{j})=1_{D}$ for all $1\leq \mathit i \leq r$ and $1\leq \mathit j \leq s$, $\mathit q_{j}$ does not divide $\mathit p_{i}$(I already proved this part) and thus $\mathit q_{j}^{n_j}$ does not divide $\mathit p_{i}^{m_{i}}$. Then since $\mathit b\ |\ c$, we get $q^{n_1}_{1}...q^{n_s}_{s}\ |\ p^{m_1}_{1}...p^{m_r}_{r}t$ and $q^{n_1}_{1}...q^{n_s}_{s}$ must divide $\mathit t$. Let $\mathit t = q^{n_1}_{1}...q^{n_s}_{s}x$ for some $x \in \mathit D$, then $$\mathit c = p^{m_1}_{1}...p^{m_r}_{r}q^{n_1}_{1}...q^{n_s}_{s}x=abx$$ Now we got the result what we want.

This is the best proof that I can come up with, but I don't have a conviction that there is no logical leap in my proof. If there is, can you indicate it?

Comment: Don't give titles like that to your posts. Give titles which are at least a little bit informative about the content. Sometimes that is difficult, and I also can't think of a good one, but something like "About divisibility in unique factorization domains" would be better, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will reflect that immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core of the proof is not completely clear. You say that $q_j$ does not divide $p_i$, ok, but how do you conclude that $q_j^{n_j}$ does not divide $p_i^{m_i}$? And how do you conclude that $q_1^{n_1}\ldots q_s^{n_s}$ must divide $t$? The suspicious thing is you have never explicitly used or even mentioned that $p_i$s and $q_j$s are primes.

Also, this is a small lemma in between: if $x$ divides $yz$ and $\gcd(x, y)=1$, then $x$ divides $z$.

Comment: I was concerned that is not clear, too. So I would suggest this theorem : If D is a UFD and p is in D, then p is irreducible in D if and only if p is prime in D. Thus each $p_{i}$-s and $q_{j}$-s are irreducible, they are also prime. If I mention this, does it becomes clear?

Comment: I mean, to me it is clear how to fill the details, the quetion is what the desired level of details is for the audience of the proof. Maybe the fact that you need some kind of induction should be also mentioned: $q_j$ divides the product, is a prime, divides a factor, the factor has to be $t$, then cancel $q_j$, take another prime on left side, and so on. In other words that the very proposition you are proving is true when $a, b$ are primes, which is easy, but not trivial.

Comment: I totally understood. Thank you for your comment very much. I will consider your comment.